# How to manually instal php 8.3 on Debian 10?

Tags: debian, software-installation, php

I use Debian 10.

I cann't install last php (8.3) from sury.org and would like to install it manually.

I can download php-8.3.4.tar.gz form php.net, but what to do next?

How to manually install php 8.3 (or later) on Debian 10?

Comment: There are plenty of resources that can be found via Google which include entire tutorials on how to install PHP 8.3 on Debian 10. Try those and then if you are having trouble, ask a question that includes what you've done and what is going wrong.